# Can't identify the recursion that triggered "maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, recursion

UPDATE: I changed the jquery.min to the full version and now the error is:
[image]

I'm new to JS and AJAX. I'm writing an AJAX post request to submit login info (username and password) to a server(provided as part of homework instruction). My login.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Log into your account</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  // A form that receives username and password as inputs

  // When you click button, func() is called
  <button type="submit" onclick="func()">Login</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The corresponding login.js looks like:

```
var func = function() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username");
  var password = document.getElementById("password");
  $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        data:{
            username: username,
            password: password
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(xhr.status==200){
                //If status is 200, redirect to another page
                window.location.href = '/redirect.html';
            }
            else{
                //If not, display a failure message
                alert('Login Failed.');
            }
        },
        dataType:"json"
    }
   )
 };
```

When I run the code, I get a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error in Chrome:
[image]

I did some research and realized that this error is usually caused by an infinitely running recursion function in the code; however, I just don't see where in my code this potential recursion might occur. Can someone tell me how I should go about this?

Comment: Is there any logic in redirect.html page load? Also, try to add an error callback function and debug to see if there is any exceptions.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh redirect.html is just a static page with a map composed of several picture fragments. Thanks for the advice! Is it possible that the server is causing this problem?

Comment: is your url variable fine? Also success function params miss the xhr param. Can you refactor your code?

Comment: `document.getElementById("username");` should be `document.getElementById("username").value` and the same for the password (or `$("username").val()` -- why aren't you using the jQuery functions?).

Comment: Go to real jQuery not the minified version (remove the .min for the file name), then we can understand where in jQuery it is happened

Comment: Try to add an error callback and see if it catches any server error? example: error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {}

Comment: Is the error happening before it sends the AJAX request, or when it's processing the response?

Comment: @ImabAsghar Yes, the url variable is fine. I just added the xhr param. Thank you!

Comment: @Amina I just changed to the real jQuery. It seems to be giving different error messages now.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh Thank you for the example, I'll try that!

Comment: @Barmar the error occurs before it sends the AJAX request - when it's processing the response. Basically, when I hit submit button, I go into a loop.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh I modified my code as everyone suggested and the error callback function tells me that the error being thrown is Bad Request 400, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) Is the ajax function hitting your server method? 2) Are you able to debug and see whether the correct parameters are passed?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh 1) Yes, the server creates a user session (the url in ajax) and handles POST to that session. 2) I changed the if statement to if(statusCode==200) and took out the xhr object. I used the example error function you showed me and it gave a very vague indication in Chrome, the error message is "POST 400 Bad Request"

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh My bad: I forgot to mention that there is no infinite loop any more; however the new error message is Bad Request 400.

Comment: Good. Now, we are able to catch the exception. You should dig into the xhr object in error callback and try to find the cause.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh thank you! I'm not very familiar with the xhr object - is there any field of xhr you would suggest to check?

Comment: As a first thing, try to stringify your data parameter. For example: data: JSON.stringify({
    username: username,
     password: password
  }), Also, in xhr object, look for responseText

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh I already corrected that in my code but thank you for pointing that out! I also added contentType:"application/json". Quick question, what's the best way to retrieve http status code in ajax(like 200, 400)? What I did was pass xhr as a param in success function, and use xhr.status to get http status code, but I gathered that wasn't correct?

Answer (score 0):

I see `param` in the jQuery function name, so I suspect it's happening when it's trying to encode the `data` parameter. The problem is that you're trying to put DOM elements into the parameters, not their values. Change

```
var username = document.getElementById("username");
var password = document.getElementById("password");
```

to:

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
```